# QT stylesheet not producing any result

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm new to QT and this is probably very basic but I can't get a stylesheet to work on my message box.

The code I have now is called from:

```py
self.actionLoad_Portfolio_Settings.triggered.connect(self.openPortfolioSettings)
```

and is:

```
def openPortfolioSettings(self):
     # some code
     QMessageBox.about(self, "Portfolio settings","Portfolio settings loaded successfullly")
     QMessageBox.setStyleSheet(self,".QMessageBox.about {border: 20px solid black;border-radius: 10px;background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);}")
```

But this doesn't do anything and the message box comes up as before.

Ultimately what I want to do is to set a stylesheet for all the dialogs, widows and main window so I can just use something like:

```
 my_stylesheet=foo
somewindow.setStyleSheet(my)stylesheet)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have syntax errors, remove the dot before `QMessageBox` and remove the `.about` piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMessageBox.about() is a static method so you can not get the object directly to set the stylesheet, so there are several strategies depending on the additional code you have and if you want to apply the same style to all QMessageBox.

If you only want to apply to the QMessageBox that generates the about method then the idea is to filter, in this case I will assume that it is the only visible QMessageBox, then a `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)` is used to obtain the widget through its parent using `findChildren()` method:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        settings_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("Settings")
        self.actionLoad_Portfolio_Settings = settings_menu.addAction(
            "Load Portafolio"
        )
        self.actionLoad_Portfolio_Settings.triggered.connect(
            self.openPortfolioSettings
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def openPortfolioSettings(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.after_about_portafolio_settings)
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(
            self,
            "Portfolio settings",
            "Portfolio settings loaded successfullly",
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def after_about_portafolio_settings(self):
        for messagebox in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QMessageBox):
            if messagebox.isVisible():
                messagebox.setStyleSheet(
                    """QMessageBox{border: 20px solid black;border-radius: 10px;background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);}"""
                )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If instead you want to apply the same style to all the QMessageBox children in the window then place the style in the stylesheet of the window:

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """
            /* another styles*/
            QMessageBox{border: 20px solid black;border-radius: 10px;background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);}
            """
        )
        settings_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("Settings")
        self.actionLoad_Portfolio_Settings = settings_menu.addAction(
            "Load Portafolio"
        )
        self.actionLoad_Portfolio_Settings.triggered.connect(
            self.openPortfolioSettings
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def openPortfolioSettings(self):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(
            self,
            "Portfolio settings",
            "Portfolio settings loaded successfullly",
        )
```

If instead you want to apply the same style for all the QMessageBox in the full application then set the stylesheet in the QApplication:

```py
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(
    """
    /* another styles*/
    QMessageBox{border: 20px solid black;border-radius: 10px;background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);}
    """
)
```

---

Another solution is to not use the QMessage.about() method but to create a QMessageBox object:

```py
def openPortfolioSettings(self):
    messagebox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoIcon,
        "Portfolio settings",
        "Portfolio settings loaded successfullly",
        parent=self,
    )
    messagebox.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    messagebox.setStyleSheet(
        """
        QMessageBox{border: 20px solid black;border-radius: 10px;background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);}
        """
    )
    messagebox.exec_()
```